# When is the set of unbounded solutions open?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ be an autonomous differential equation:
\begin{align}
x' = f(x)
\end{align}
where $f'(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{1}$.  Consider the set $\Omega$
\begin{align}
\Omega := \{\alpha \text{ such that } x_{\alpha} \text{ is unbounded on } [0,\omega) \text{ for some } \omega < \infty \}.
\end{align}

Where $x_{\alpha}$ represents the solution $x(t)$ where $x(0) = \alpha$.  Show that $\Omega$ is open.

Here is what I have done so far,

I have separated the equation so we have that 
\begin{align}
\int_{\alpha}^{x(t)} \frac{dx}{f(x)} &= \int_{0}^{T}dt \\
T &= \int_{\alpha}^{x(t)} \frac{dx}{f(x)}
\end{align}

I am wondering what I can use about $f$ to get strict bounds on $\alpha$.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{x:f(x)=0\}$ be the set of stationary points of the equation. This set is closed and is disjoint from $\Omega$. Its complement $\mathbb R\setminus S$ is the union of disjoint open intervals (connected components).  If $I$ is such an interval, then for any $\alpha\in I$ the solution $x_\alpha$ takes values in $I$ only. (It cannot jump across an equilibrium, by  uniqueness theorem.) In particular, bounded components of $\mathbb R\setminus S$ are disjoint from $\Omega$.

Let $I$ be an unbounded component of $\mathbb R\setminus S$. I claim that $I$ is either disjoint from $\Omega$ or is contained in it; this is enough to prove the openness of $\Omega$. For definiteness, assume $I=(a,\infty)$; other types of unbounded intervals can be handled similarly. Suppose $\alpha_0\in I\cap \Omega$. Then $x_{\alpha_0}$ is unbounded from above, which implies $f>0$ on $I$. Consider $\alpha\in I$. The solution $x_\alpha$ is increasing and does not have a horizontal asymptote, for such an asymptote would be a zero of $f$. Therefore, $x_\alpha(t_0)>\alpha_0$ for some $t_0$. Since both $x_\alpha$ and $x_{\alpha_0}$ attain the   value $x_\alpha(t_0)$, it follows (again by uniqueness) that $x_\alpha$ is a time-shift of $x_{\alpha_0}$. Therefore, $x_\alpha$  also becomes unbounded  on a finite interval. This proves $I\subset \Omega$, as claimed.